# Filepond revert method for delete does not send unique file id

Tags: javascript, python, flask, request, filepond

I am trying to intergrate File Pond with my Flask server and I can not find the unique file id it sends with requests. With normal uploads it will show me request data on the server, but without the unique ID I am looking for. I want to use this unique ID to attach to a database in order to delete the file if the revert is sent later.

Going over [the docs,](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#revert) it is suppsoed to send a unique ID with every upload, but I can't tell if it's a bad config in file pond or I suck at reading request.files. Just ignore all my prints where I try to read the contents of request.

Here is my FilePond Config:

```
    FilePond.setOptions({
        //allowImageEdit: true,
        //allowImageCrop: true,
        //allowMultiple: true,
        //allowFileEncode: true,
        allowImageExifOrientation: true,
        credits: false,
        server: {
            process: {
                url: './pondupload',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'x-customheader': 'Hello World',
                },
                withCredentials: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
                onload: (response) => response.key,
                onerror: (response) => response.data,
                ondata: (formData) => {
                    formData.append('csrf_token', document.getElementById('csrf_token').value)
                    return formData;
                },
            },
            revert: './pondupload',
            restore: './restore/',
            load: './load/',
            fetch: './fetch/',
        },
    });
```

Here is my route in flask:

```
@bp.route('/pondupload', methods=['POST', 'DELETE'])
def pondupload():
    print ('data: '+str(request.data))
    print('form: '+str(request.form))
    print('files: '+str(request.files))
    print('args: '+str(request.args))
    form=EmptyForm()
    #TODO add csrf to revert
    if request.method == "DELETE":
        print('delete stuff')
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        upload_dir = current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
        fn = ""
        file_names = []
        # get file object from request.files (see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.files)
        for key in request.files:
            print('key: '+str(key))
            file = request.files[key]
            fn = secure_filename(file.filename)
            if allowed_file(fn) == True:
                file_names.append(fn)
                try:
                    file.save(os.path.join(upload_dir, fn))
                    return jsonify({}), 200
                except:
                    return jsonify(filename=file_names), 402
    return jsonify({}), 400
```

Comment: The unique id FilePond uses for request (all but process) is the unique id returned in the process method. I see you use `onload: (response) => response.key` so your response should have { key: "<unique id>" }. I advise to open the browser network tab and inspect the server response. Then if it's there, log "response" in the onload function so you can see what you get.

Comment: I took response.key from their code and did not know what it did. Currently it has nothing in it by default. In that case, I assume this means it is not looking for anything from my server. Since response.key does not load anything by default what is suggested to be there?

Comment: FilePond will use what you set in that function, so if it's empty, your file id's will all be undefined.

Comment: I set a string in it to test and it is still reporting Undefined to my server which also drops the requirement for it to report back anything. Is this a bug?

Comment: Filepond is sending my response.key for the DELETE method, but does not check if my server returns anything besides a 200. Further I am unable to even get response.key into the ondata function by appending it to formData. Ideally, my server needs the unique ID for both funcitons to figure out which file it is dealing with for a revert, but it appears not to be working as intended.

Comment: This is not a bug. The client server communication process is outlined here. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process Again, I advise to open the browser network tab and inspect the server response.